# Deleting the record from a table referenced by 60 foreign keys

Tags: sql-server-2012

Table takes a long time to delete one record. It is referenced by 60 foreign key tables and when all the child records are deleted, I started to delete one record but it takes one minute.

Comment: If you're deleting the a row which is referenced by that many tables (which honestly sounds like a design flaw), and you have cascading enabled then this is going to very likely end up with a huge waterfall effect. You're not just going to be deleting 1 row, but **every** row that has a relationship to that row (which includes rows that reference rows that reference the row you are deleting). That could end up with 1,000's of rows in the end.

Comment: Honestly, for things like this, it's often better/easier to have a column you use to denote if a row is "active" or not. Then just update the column with an appropriate value to denote it's been "deleted"; perhaps you use a date & time and `NULL` means it's active, or a `bit` column and `1` means deleted. Then, after you add the column, changed your queries to exclude rows that are marked as "deleted". This will also result in preservation of history; which may be very important to retain in its own right.

Comment: My question is that I had written a procedure to delete the record consisting of given ID number from all tables . After deleting all the records from child tables only the parent will left to delete. So ,now I can delete the record because all the foreign keys are deleted. but it takes time to delete.My doubt is that may it again checks all the tables and then delete?

Comment: If you're asking a performance question, we need to query and the query plan (search Paste the Plan). Without those, we can only guess